# Are deities visible on an idol for those who attained state of Turiya?

Tags: tantra

To those who're (have attained) turiya, are the deities actually visible in their sukshma sharira rupa on an idol or a place which has prana parthishta done? for example I've read somewhere that In the emptiness chamber of chidambaram, Shiva & Parvati are visible in sukshma sharira to those who're turiya or something like that. as well as Sri M recounts seeing lord Shiva at Mt Kailash in another dimension.